# Understanding base cases of inductive proofs in algorithm analysis Cormen et al

Tags: algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am currently working through Cormen et al's classic book on algorithms and data structures. I am trying to follow an inductive substitution  proof that the following time complexity function is $O(n\circ  lg(n))$:

$T(n) = 2T([\frac{n}{2}]) + \Theta(n)$.

I am not quite following the details of his proof. His basic method is this:

$\textbf{Proof Strategy}$

"Suppose that, for all $n'$ such that $n_0 \leq n' \leq n$ we have it that $T(n') = c \circ n' \circ lg(n)'$ (that is, that $T(n) = O(n \circ lg(n))$). Then $T(n) \leq c \circ n \circ lg(n)$."

Now, he show that  $T(n) \leq c \circ n \circ lg(n)$ when $n \geq 2\circ n_0$, and then he moves to the base cases. It is here when I lose him. He says:

> We have shown that the induction holds for the inductive case, but we also need to prove that the inductive hypothesis holds for the base cases of the induction, that is, that $T(n) \leq c\circ n\circ lg(n) $when $n_0 \leq n < 2n_0$. As long as $n_0 > 1 \ldots$ we have $lg(n) > 0$. So let's pick $n_0 = 2$. Since the base case of the recurrence (shown above) is not stated explicitly, by our convention, $T(n)$ is algorithmic, which means that $T(2)$ and $T(3)$ are constant (as they should be if they describe the worst-case running time of any real program on inputs of size $2$ or $3$). Picking $c = max\{T(2),T(3)\}$ yields $T(2) \leq c < (2\circ lg(2))\circ c$ and $T(3) \leq c < (3 \circ lg(3)\circ c$, establishing the inductive hypothesis for the base cases. (Cormen et al, 2022: 91)

I don't follow the reasoning here on a few counts. First of all, I thought this was a strong induction, so I'm not used to hearing about explicit base cases in a strong induction. Secondly and more specifically, I don't understand why he excludes $T(1)$. The definition of big O allow $0 \leq f(n) \leq c\circ g(n)$. So even if $c \circ 1 \circ lg(1) = 0$, what's the problem, technically speaking?

It seems at this stage the proof switches from fully formal mathematical reasoning to reasoning which involves background assumptions regarding the time complexity of algorithms. I wonder if anyone can help me understand Cormen's treatment of base cases here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I'm not used to hearing about explicit base cases in a strong induction"?

Comment: The problem with using $n=1$ as a base case is that $T(1)>0$, so you will never have $T(1)\leqslant c\cdot 1 \cdot \lg(1)=0$.

Comment: @user469053 Yes - sure. In a strong induction, to my understanding, we say: "Let $\phi$ be a property. Suppose that, for every number n, the following conditional holds: if all $n' < n$ has $\phi$, then $n$ itself has $\phi$. Then every number has $\phi$.' We then prove that conditional is indeed the case for an arbitrary $n$. We don't bother to prove that for the smallest $n$ - let's say $0$, because the conditional holds for the smallest element vacuously. So, when I've seen and done strong inductions before, there's never been need for a base case.

Comment: @user469053 I see. So we are relying on the assumption that we are dealing with algorithms here, and algorithms will always take some non-negative time to execute - that is, we are assuming that, $T(n) > 0$ for all $n$. Is that right?

Comment: If we had a collection $P(n)$ of propositions, for $n=0,1,\ldots$, and if we showed that the truth of $P(n')$ for all $n>n'\in \{0,1,\ldots\}$ implies the truth of $P(n)$, that would indeed give the truth of $P(0)$. But that inductive step would include proving that $P(0)$ holds.

Comment: I would say it is safe to assume that $T(1)>0$. However, I would also say that we don't need to say something that is quite that strong. Even in the absence of assuming that $T(1)>0$, we don't know whether or not $T(1)>0$. So we leave open the possibility that $T(1)=0$, but since we still have the possibility that $T(1)>0$, we can't majorize ti by $0$.

Comment: @user469053 OK – I think I'm starting to see. In the case of this proof, the inductive case involves showing that, for all $n > 2n_0$, $T(n) \leq c n lg(n)$ because $T([\frac{n}{2}]) \leq c[\frac{n}{2}]lg([\frac{n}{2}])$. But we haven't shown anything about the cases where $n \leq 2n_0$, and so that's why we must deal with these cases explicitly – hence they become base cases. Is that the right way to think about it?

Comment: All inductive proofs have at least one base case. What you're describing is performing the base case(s) and the inductive step at the same time, which I have honestly never seen. Do you have an example of such a proof, or could you outline one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151735/discussion-between-dan-oz-and-user469053).

Comment: Yes @user469053. Please follow this link https://dl.ebooksworld.ir/books/Introduction.to.Algorithms.4th.Leiserson.Stein.Rivest.Cormen.MIT.Press.9780262046305.EBooksWorld.ir.pdf

and see page 90-91. That is where the proof is.